# Where is Powershell in the Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I killed the terminal of the powershell by pressing on the button in Visual Studio Code in terminal.

There is one terminal cmd only. How to choose the terminal from all available in VSC?

I killed the terminal by the button encircled by red colour:

[image: vscode screenshot]

Comment: You can either start a new powershell by just opening it from the cmd (just type `powershell`). Or you can edit your standard shell by using editing it in the options like this: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"`

Comment: Also take a look at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal